# .Net 7 Quick Grid Filter Not Refreshing Properly

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0, quickgrid

I have a grid with both Template and Property Columns (code below only showing a single column.) The grid seems to work as expected with sorting and filtering. However, I want a way to clear all filters. I know how I would do this and it is just clearing each of the variables tied to each of the filtered columns (like `filterProjectName` below.) So, I need to UI to display a button when there is at least 1 filter in place. I have code in the Filtered data property that determines if we have any filters and then totals them up. This always seems to be a step behind what is actual (the `@CurrentFilters.Count` below.) Despite the `Console.WriteLine` that shows the correct number when the property returns.

Here is my HTML:

```
<label class="ms-3">Filters: @CurrentFilters.Count</label>

<div class="fs-08">
  <QuickGrid @ref="MyWorkGrid" Items="FilteredQuickProjects" ItemKey="@(p => p.ProjectId)" Pagination="QuickPagination" Class="table table-fixed table-sm table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <TemplateColumn Title="Project Name" Class="project-name text-truncate" Sortable="true" SortBy="sortProjectName">
      <ColumnOptions>
        <div class="search-box">
          <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-xs" autofocus @bind="filterProjectName" @bind:event="oninput" placeholder="Project Name..." />
        </div>
      </ColumnOptions>
      <ChildContent>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start">
          ...
        </div>
      </ChildContent>
    </TemplateColumn>
  </QuickGrid>
  <Paginator Value="QuickPagination" />
</div>
```

The code behind is:

```
public HashSet<string> CurrentFilters { get; set; } = new();
public QuickGrid<MyWorkViewModel> MyWorkGrid { get; set; }

public IQueryable<MyWorkViewModel> FilteredQuickProjects
{
  get
  {
    if (!PageIsLoaded)
      return MyQuickProjects;

    CurrentFilters.Clear();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterProjectName))
    {
      result = result.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filterProjectName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
      CurrentFilters.Add("ProjectName");
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine($"Total Filters: {CurrentFilters.Count}");

    return result;
  }
}
```

I put `StateHasChanged()` at the end of the `FilteredQuickProjects` and that had created an endless loop.

I am not sure what to do here.